# Creating folders by using object values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am learning Nodejs, and I am trying to create folders for each new user.
The folder will be linked to the User name (when clicking on it will open folder/ftp)
I am using the Admin-bro interface.

Here is the User object.

```
const { model } = require("mongoose");

const User = model("User", {
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  age: Number,
  email: String,
  description: String
});

module.exports = User;
```

User router:

```
const { Router } = require('express')
const paginate = require('../services/paginate.service')
const User = require('../models/user.model')

const dir = require('../routers/ftp')
const router = new Router()

const serializer = (user) => {
  return user.toObject({ versionKey: false })
}

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const users = await paginate(User.find({}), req)
  res.send(users.map(serializer))
})

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await new User(req.body.user).save()
  res.send(serializer(user))

})

module.exports = router
```

I have no idea how to create a folder for each new user I add, passing name_surname as the folder name.
I trying to create a router but failed.

This is what I tried:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = function(app) {
  const fs = require("fs");
  const path = require("path");
  const multer = require("multer");

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    desctination: function(req, file, cb) {
      const uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", `${Date.now()}`);
      fs.mkdirSync(uploadDir);
      cb(null, uploadDir);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({ storage });
  const controller = require("../routers/createDir");


};
```

PS: there is no controller as I don't know what do to.

Please give me an advice or a link where I can learn how it's done. Thank you

Comment: So you want to create a directory when a new user signs up?

Comment: I am adding the user manully from the admin panel 
https://prnt.sc/pr4r9t
and i want to create a directoru for each user like that i create using user name_surname

Answer (score 0):

User `mkdrp` node module package

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

mkdirp('/tmp/foo/bar/baz', function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err)
  else console.log('pow!')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to pass the user name or id to the folder and create it dynamically, not manually. smth like this

```
const multer = require("multer");
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    const { userId } = req.body;
    const dir = `../uploads/${userId}`;
    fs.exists(dir, exist => {
      if (!exist) {
        return fs.mkdir(dir, error => cb(error, dir));
      }
      return cb(null, dir);
    });
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const { userId } = req.body;
    cb(null, `UserId-${userId}-Image-${Date.now()}.png`);
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
```